# Yii framework - Javascript error when CGridView is inside a tab

Tags: javascript, php, yii

In Yii Framework when I place a CGridView inside a tab, I get a javascript error:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function index.php?r=department/view&id=2:121
(anonymous function) index.php?r=department/view&id=2:121 fire jquery.js:974 self.fireWith jquery.js:1084 jQuery.extend.ready jquery.js:406 DOMContentLoaded"
```

Everything is working fine, but I'm worried about that error. What could it be?
Here's the code from the main page and also the render page used in the tab.

```
$tabs = $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs', array(
        'id' => 'tabs',
        'type' => 'tabs',
        'tabs' => array(
            array('label' => 'Users', 'content' => $this->renderPartial('_admin', array('model' => $model), true, true)),
        ),
    ));
```

Render page:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'id'=>'user-grid',
    'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'name',
        'job',
        array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Thank you.

HTML Output

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="language" content="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/themes/bootstrap/css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/themes/bootstrap/css/form.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/themes/bootstrap/css/jquery-ui-override.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/e3ecaab1/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/e3ecaab1/css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/e3ecaab1/css/yii.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/76299ef8/jquery.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/76299ef8/jquery.ba-bbq.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/e3ecaab1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<title>iManage - View Department</title>
    </head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top"><div class="navbar-inner"><div class="container"><a href="/index.php" class="brand">iManage</a><ul id="yw4" class="nav"><li><a href="/index.php?r=site/index"><i class="icon-home"></i> Home</a></li><li><a href="/index.php?r=user/admin"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i> Users</a></li><li class="active"><a href="/index.php?r=department/admin"><i class="icon-tags"></i> Departments</a></li><li><a href="/index.php?r=site/logout">Logout (admin)</a></li></ul></div></div></div>
<div class="container" id="page">
            <ul class="breadcrumbs breadcrumb"><li><a href="/index.php">Home</a><span class="divider">/</span></li><li><a href="/index.php?r=department/index">Departments</a><span class="divider">/</span></li><li class="active">903</li></ul><!-- breadcrumbs -->
        <div class="row">
        <div class="span3">
            <div id="sidebar">
                <ul class="side-menu nav nav-list" id="yw3"><li class="nav-header">Operations</li><li><a href="/index.php?r=department/admin"><i class="icon-th"></i> Manage Departments</a></li><li><a href="/index.php?r=department/index"><i class="icon-th-list"></i> List Departments</a></li><li><a href="/index.php?r=department/create"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i> Create Department</a></li><li class="active"><a><i class="icon-eye-open"></i> View Department</a></li><li><a href="/index.php?r=department/update&amp;id=903"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Update Department</a></li></ul></div>
        </div>
        <div class="span9">
            <div id="content">
<h1>View Users</h1>
<div id="tabs"><ul id="yw2" class="nav nav-tabs"><li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs_tab_1">Users</a></li></ul><div class="tab-content"><div id="tabs_tab_1" class="tab-pane active"><script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/76299ef8/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/76299ef8/jquery.ba-bbq.js"></script>
<div id="department-grid" class="grid-view">
<div class="summary">Displaying 1-1 of 1 result.</div>
<table class="items table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
<thead>
<tr>
<th id="department-grid_c0"><a class="sort-link" href="/index.php?r=department/view&amp;id=903&amp;Department_sort=id">ID<span class="caret"></span></a></th><th id="department-grid_c1"><a class="sort-link" href="/index.php?r=department/view&amp;id=903&amp;Department_sort=designation">Designation<span class="caret"></span></a></th><th class="button-column" id="department-grid_c2">&nbsp;</th></tr>
<tr class="filters">
<td><div class="filter-container"><input name="Department[id]" type="text" value="903"></div></td><td><div class="filter-container"><input name="User[name]" type="text" maxlength="255" value="John Doe"></div></td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">
<td>903</td><td>John Smith</td><td class="button-column"><a class="view" title="View" rel="tooltip" href="/index.php?r=department/view&amp;id=903"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i></a> <a class="update" title="Update" rel="tooltip" href="/index.php?r=department/update&amp;id=903"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a> <a class="delete" title="Delete" rel="tooltip" href="/index.php?r=department/delete&amp;id=903"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="keys" style="display:none" title="/index.php?r=department/view&amp;id=903"><span>903</span></div>
</div><script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/468c8877/gridview/jquery.yiigridview.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery(document).on('click','#department-grid a.delete',function() {
    if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')) return false;
    var th = this,
        afterDelete = function(){};
    jQuery('#department-grid').yiiGridView('update', {
        type: 'POST',
        url: jQuery(this).attr('href'),
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#department-grid').yiiGridView('update');
            afterDelete(th, true, data);
        },
        error: function(XHR) {
            return afterDelete(th, false, XHR);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
jQuery('#department-grid').yiiGridView({'ajaxUpdate':['department-grid'],'ajaxVar':'ajax','pagerClass':'pagination','loadingClass':'grid-view-loading','filterClass':'filters','tableClass':'items table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed','selectableRows':1,'enableHistory':false,'updateSelector':'{page}, {sort}','filterSelector':'{filter}','pageVar':'Department_page'});
/*]]>*/
</script>
</div></div></div>            </div>
            <!-- content -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<!-- page -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/468c8877/gridview/jquery.yiigridview.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery(function($) {
jQuery(document).on('click','#department-grid a.delete',function() {
    if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')) return false;
    var th = this,
        afterDelete = function(){};
    jQuery('#department-grid').yiiGridView('update', {
        type: 'POST',
        url: jQuery(this).attr('href'),
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#department-grid').yiiGridView('update');
            afterDelete(th, true, data);
        },
        error: function(XHR) {
            return afterDelete(th, false, XHR);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
jQuery('#department-grid').yiiGridView({'ajaxUpdate':['department-grid'],'ajaxVar':'ajax','pagerClass':'pagination','loadingClass':'grid-view-loading','filterClass':'filters','tableClass':'items table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed','selectableRows':1,'enableHistory':false,'updateSelector':'{page}, {sort}','filterSelector':'{filter}','pageVar':'Department_page'});
jQuery('#tabs').tab('show');
jQuery('body').tooltip({'selector':'a[rel=tooltip]'});
jQuery('body').popover({'selector':'a[rel=popover]'});
});
/*]]>*/
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Please post your full HTML Output. Thanks.

Comment: Just added the html output. Thank you.